# How exactly do views and NavigationLink()'s work in swiftUI?

Tags: swift, navigation, swiftui, swift5

When you navigate to a new view with NavigationLink(destination: View()) does the old view get deleted or does the new view just appear over the old view with it still existing in the background?

For example, if I have a view called GameView(). And in GameView there is a button called NavigationLink(label: "New Game", destination: GameView()) when new game is pressed will the previous game view be automatically deleted/removed or does it still exist and need some other code to properly remove it?

Comment: It wont get deleted. And, in fact, it can programmatically navigate back to itself.

Comment: @NewDev Thanks for the response. Is it bad practice to create views like this? Going off my example, if a person is playing the game for the 8th time, wouldn't the other 7 games still be using resources in the background? Is there a way to create a new view without the old one using background resources?

Comment: There's the usual way displaying the view based on state value: `if level == 1 { Game1View() } else { Game2View() }`. This is simplified, but you get the point, right?

Comment: @NewDev Yes, that makes sense. Thank you!